# Solving an issue with int + string

Tags: java, string, integer

I am literally new into any programming. I'd like to know if there is a way to convert an integer into a string? I did some Google research but it didn't quite answer my question.

What I am trying to do is this:
I have an `int cardValue = (int)(Math.random() * 13 + 1);`

It takes (should at least) a random value between 1 and 13. Later in the code it prints out cardValue + cardType into the console, for example "2 of Aces". What I want is that if the value of the card is 1, 11, 12 or 13 it would print out "Queen of Diamonds", for example, rather than "12 of Diamonds".

Card types are printed as follows and I know there must be a better way for this so any suggestions will be noted aswell:

```
if (cardType == 1){
 System.out.println("You got: " + cardValue + aces);
 }else if (cardType == 2) {
 System.out.println("You got: " + cardValue + spades);
 }else if (cardType == 3) {
 System.out.println("You got: " + cardValue + cross);
 }else {
 System.out.println("You got: " + cardValue + diamonds);
 }
}
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Prior to printing out the value of your `cardValue` variable, you can translate it into a human-readable result using a few simple `if` statements. There are four special cases to account for: Ace, Jack, Queen, King. You can handle each of these using distinct `if`/`else-if` statements. Define a new method for translating from `cardValue` to the text that you want to output, the `cardName`:

```
private static String getCardName(int cardValue) {
    // By default, you just output the number as is
    String cardName = "" + cardValue;

    if (cardValue == 1) {
        cardName = "Ace";
    }
    else if (cardValue == 11) {
        cardName = "Jack";
    }
    else if (cardValue == 12) {
        cardName = "Queen";
    }
    else if (cardValue == 13) {
        cardName = "King";
    }

    return cardName;
}
```

Then, simply use this new method `getCardName(cardValue)` to translate to the desired output format, and use the result in your `println` statements.

Comment: use a switch instead of multiple if

Comment: @Tokazio Thanks for the suggestion! That's definitely a valid alternative solution, but it introduces a new statement/syntax that the OP isn't necessarily familiar with as a beginner to programming, and one which does not seem essential to include in a solution for someone learning the basics. That's just my opinion though.

Comment: If anyone's interested, they can find more details on the [`switch` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) here, and learn more about how it can replace multiple `if`/`else if` statements like this one.

Comment: you're right, it's just a comment to indicate this another more readable option that i think is good to learn too.

Comment: That's great advice. Thank you so much!

Comment: Although I have some hard time understanding few parts of the syntax. If it's not too much trouble, could you explain the following so I can understand Java a bit better:

private static String getCardName(int cardValue) <-- why "int cardValue" needs to be introduced here?

String cardName = "" + cardValue; <-- And why we add the cardValue here when it doesn't show anywhere?

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

use a String array olding the text value at the card value index like

```
String[] txt = {"a","Queen"};
System.out.println(txt[1]);
```

will output 'Queen' (assuming 1 is your card value)

or

use a Enum for your cardType (and/or card value) and give it a text field to hold the name you want to print

```
Enum CardType{
    DIAMON("Diamon"),
    ACE("Ace");

    public String name;

    public CardType(String text){
        name = text;
    }

    public String toString(){
         return name;
    }
}

System.out.println(CardType.ACE);
```

will output 'Ace'